# passing function from parent to child component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to do a single page application navigation, so the components load into the page container when the user clicks on menu links. This is what I've tried:

**App.tsx:**

```
import * as React from 'react';

import Home from './components/Home';
import MainMenu from './components/MainMenu';
import SignUp from './components/SignUp';

interface IProps {
  SignUp?: boolean;
}

interface IState{
  SignUp: boolean;
}

class App extends React.Component<IProps,IState>
{
  constructor(props: IProps, state: IState) {
    super(props);
    this.renderPage = this.renderPage.bind(this);
    this.state = state;
    this.setState({
      SignUp: false
    });
  }

  public renderPage(page: string)
  {
    if(page === 'SignUp')
    {
        this.setState({
          SignUp: true
        });
    }
  }

  public render()
  {
    let page = <Home/>;

    if(this.state.SignUp)
    {
      page = <SignUp/>;
    }

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <MainMenu renderPage={this.renderPage}/>
        <div className="container-fluid">
           {page}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**MainMenu.tsx:**

```
import * as React from 'react';

import './Home.css';

interface IProps
{
    renderPage: (page: string) => void
}

class MainMenu extends React.Component<IProps> {
  public render() {
    return (
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li className="nav-item active">
                        <a className="nav-link" href="#" onClick={this.props.renderPage('Home')}>
                            Home
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li className="nav-item">
                        <a className="nav-link" href="#" onClick={this.props.renderPage('SignUp')}>
                            Sign Up
                        </a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    );
  }
}

export default MainMenu;
```

I got this error in MainMenu.tsx:

> Type 'void' is not assignable to type '((event:
>   MouseEvent) => void) | undefined'.

Comment: Why not use a router like `react-router-dom` to render different views based on `<a>` clicks?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky actually I don't know if this is the proper way to make a single page application, it's my first react app

Answer (score 2):

Inside MainMenu component you invoke the passed function, not assingn it to an a element.

```
<a className="nav-link" href="#" onClick={() => this.props.renderPage('SignUp')}>
    Sign Up
</a>
```

The example above should solve the error, even though you don't pass the event argument.

However, wouldn't it be better if you used react-router, which handles rendering components depending on navigation?

Comment: you can't use Lambda functions in JSX

Comment: Have you tried this or you just assume it can't work? Here is declared a function triggered on event. This is common in React.